# Flutter double paint value calculation errors

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Getting this error:

The setter 'value=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: value=3000.0

```
final WallheightController = TextEditingController();
final WalllengthController = TextEditingController();
var height;
var length;
var area;
RxDouble paint = 0.2.obs;
RxDouble result=0.0 .obs;
calculatepaint() {
  if (WallheightController.text.isNotEmpty ||
      WalllengthController.text.isNotEmpty ) {
     height = double.parse(WallheightController.text);
     length = double.parse(WalllengthController.text);

    area.value = (height * length);
    result.value = area.value* paint.value;

    Get.toNamed(RoutesClass.prcalculation);
   } else {
    Get.snackbar("Fields empty", "Fill Required fields");
  }
}

clear() {
  WallheightController.clear();
  WalllengthController.clear();
}
```

I am trying to calculate paint on an area of a wall but getting this error

Answer (score 1):

make `var area = 0.0.obs;`

**you are using area.value so you need to make area .obs**

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your and I have noticed something that I want to share with you.

1. You should always try to use variables with proper types like `double, int, String` and try to omit the `var` keyword as much as possible.
2. When you are using GetX for your State Management solution, you can either make the variable reactive by **.obs** or you can set your variable as it. But whenever you want to reflect the changes in the UI you can call the `update()` method at the end of your task or function.

Therefore there are mainly 2 answers to your question:

1. You can make the variables reactive by .obs like this:

```js
final WallheightController = TextEditingController();
final WalllengthController = TextEditingController();
late double height; // I have used late because we are not assigning the value when declaring the variable
late double length;
RxDouble area = 0.0.obs;
RxDouble paint = 0.2.obs;
RxDouble result = 0.0.obs;
calculatepaint() {
  if (WallheightController.text.isNotEmpty ||
      WalllengthController.text.isNotEmpty ) {

    height = double.parse(WallheightController.text);
    length = double.parse(WalllengthController.text);

    area.value = (height * length);
    result.value = area.value* paint.value;

    Get.toNamed(RoutesClass.prcalculation);

   } else {
    Get.snackbar("Fields empty", "Fill Required fields");
  }
}
```

2. You can use `update()` method:

```js
final WallheightController = TextEditingController();
final WalllengthController = TextEditingController();
late double height; // I have used late because we are not assigning the value when declaring the variable
late double length;
double area = 0.0;
double paint = 0.2;
double result = 0.0;
calculatepaint() {
  if (WallheightController.text.isNotEmpty ||
      WalllengthController.text.isNotEmpty ) {

    height = double.parse(WallheightController.text);
    length = double.parse(WalllengthController.text);

    area = (height * length);
    result = area* paint;
    update();

    Get.toNamed(RoutesClass.prcalculation);

   } else {
    update();
    Get.snackbar("Fields empty", "Fill Required fields");
  }
}
```

If you are using second method, then don't forget to Wrap your code with `GetBuilder` instead of `Obx`.

Comment: Yes it solved my problem and was a very good guidance for me thankyou very much for support will support you as well